# Is it possible to use complex numbers as target labels in scikit learn?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sklearn to predict a variable that represents rotation. Because of the unfortunate jump from -pi to pi at the extremes of rotation, I think a much better method would be to use a complex number as the target. That way an error from 1+0.01j to 1-0.01j is not as devastating.

I cannot find any documentation that describes whether sklearn supports complex numbers as targets to classifiers. In theory the distance metric should work just fine, so it should work for at least some regression algorithms.

Can anyone suggest how I can get a regression algorithm to operate with complex numbers as targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I discovered that most classifiers, like linear regressors, will automatically convert complex numbers to just the real part.

kNN and RadiusNN regressors, however, work well - since they do a weighted average of the neighbor labels and so handle complex numbers gracefully.

Using a multi-target classifier is another option, however I do not want to decouple the x and y directions since that may lead to unstable solutions as Colonel Panic mentions, when both results come out close to 0.

I will try other classifiers with complex targets and update the results here.

Comment: indeed, as Colonel Panic mentioned, using the norm and the phase of the complex target a 2D float encoding instead of the real an imaginary parts might make more sense for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Several regressors support multidimensional regression targets. Just view the complex numbers as 2d points.

Comment: To make andy's answer even clearer, no sklearn regressor I know of will accept complex numbers in the target variable (nor in the input variables). The assume either 32 or 64 bits floats. An explicit 2D float encoding of the real and imaginary parts of the complex variable should work though.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. How about transforming angles into a pair of labels, viz. x and y co-ordinates. These are continuous functions of angle (cos and sin). You can combine the results from separate x and y classifiers for an angle? $\theta = \sign(x) \arctan(y/x)$. However that result will be unstable if both classifiers return numbers near zero.

Comment: Fyi, numpy has a handy function called 'arctan2' which will return theta with the correct quadrant given an x and y offset.