# Any suggestions for a Python Lasso solver that handles complex values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mathematical-optimization

I am looking for a Python Lasso solver that works with complex numbers to use in beamforming problems. The objective function is affine, XW - Y. I believe that there at least one such solver implemented for Matlab,

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Software/code.html

I have tried to use scikit-learn MultiTaskLasso, following a suggestion from

[Is it possible to use complex numbers as target labels in scikit learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999147/is-it-possible-to-use-complex-numbers-as-target-labels-in-scikit-learn)

The matrix 21 norm in the MultiTaskLasso is the correct way to handle the L1 norm for complex numbers. However, my approach requires some gymnastics to force the solver to follow the rules of complex multiplication. Essentially, I need to minimize the L2 norm of

[Re{X}, Im{X}] * [[Re{W}, Im{W}], [-Im{W}, Re{W}]] - [Re{Y}, Im{Y}]

I attempted to enforce the relationship between the two columns of W by adding another row to the X matrix, [-Im{X}, Re{X}], and the row [-Im{Y}, Re{Y}] to Y. This ideally would equate the cost of a change a value each column of W with the corresponding value in the other column

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import MultiTaskLasso

# experiment specifications
numEl = 20
numLook = 1e2
arrayPosition = np.arange(numEl) * np.pi
thetaLook = np.r_[0 : np.pi : numLook * 1j] - (np.pi / 2)
thetaSource = -0.3758

# Make grid of look vectors
W = np.exp(1j * np.sin(thetaLook)[:,None] * arrayPosition)
data = np.exp(1j * np.sin(thetaSource) * arrayPosition).T

# Bartlet beamformer
bartlet = np.abs(np.dot(W.conj(), data))**2
B_bart = 10 * np.log10(np.abs(bartlet)); B_bart-=np.max(B_bart)

# Lasso setup
X = W.T
XSplit = np.vstack((np.hstack((X.real, X.imag)),\
                    np.hstack((-X.imag, X.real))))
YSplit = np.hstack((np.vstack((data.real, data.imag)),\
                    np.vstack((-data.imag, data.real)))).T
lasso_solver = MultiTaskLasso(alpha=0.1)
lasso = lasso_solver.fit(XSplit, YSplit).coef_

# Manipulate result back into complex values
stack1 = np.squeeze(lasso[0,:])
stack1 = np.squeeze(stack1[:numLook] + 1j * stack1[numLook:])
B_lasso = 10 * np.log10(np.abs(stack1) + np.spacing(1)); B_lasso -= np.max(B_lasso)

# stack1 ?= stack2 (Should be exact)
stack2 = np.squeeze(lasso[1,:])
stack2 = np.squeeze(-1j * stack2[:numLook] + stack2[numLook:])
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(stack1, stack2, decimal=1)

# Plot both beamformer results
_ = plt.plot(np.rad2deg(thetaLook), B_bart)
_ = plt.plot(np.rad2deg(thetaLook), B_lasso, 'r.')
_ = plt.ylim(-40,3); plt.ylabel('Beamformer Output, dB')
_ = plt.xlabel('Look Direction, deg')
```

While this approach seems to work for simple problems like the one above, it fails when the problems get more complicated. I define failure when the relationship between the first and second column of W no longer holds. A simple way to create small divergent behavior in the above example is to substitute a Ridge solver for the MultiTaskLasso.

Does anyone know of a Lasso solver that can solve the complex valued problem with rigorous treatment of complex numbers?

Comment: complex numbers are 2d vectors like any other. No reason to treat them as complex numbers for lasso.

Comment: I edited the post to make it clear I have an affine objective function, XW-Y. Splitting the result vector W into a real and imaginary column leads to the proper definition of the L1 norm for complex numbers. However, my challenge is to get the real solver to follow the rules of complex math in the objective function. I believe it is impossible to do this without creating a result matrix W that has a strict relationship between two columns. This relationship between the columns of W is detailed in the problem description, but I do not know of a way to force the solver to follow it.

Comment: @SlaterVictoroff complex numbers are not  just like 2d vectors. 

First of all their aritmetic is not the same, but this could be fixed by doubling the dimensions of the linear operator.

However, lasso regularization tends to promote sparse solutions, which is not so true if you split real and imaginary parts.

For example:
[  1 , 2j, 3j ]
would be considered sparser than
[ 1+j, 3+j, 0 ]
which is not true.